# If file exists script

Tags: php, require

I'm working with a static page at MySite/Topics/index.php that displays dynamic pages via PHP and MySQL. I want to create two parallel series of dynamic pages (URL and URL2) that display content from three possible locations.

1) By default, each dynamic page (e.g. MySite/Topics/Ecology) displays content stored in a database table (and if there's nothing in the database table, that page displays no content at all).

2) I've created a series of "shadow pages" with URL's like MySite/Topics/Ecology2 that display content stored in a text file of the same name with the "2" stripped out (e.g. Ecology.php). These pages are useful for articles I'm still working on or for storing notes.

3) If the static page doesn't exist, then I want to default to a different page, like Workshop.php. The URL will be the same - MySite/Topics/Whatever - but instead of displaying content from Whatever.php (which doesn't exist in this case), it displays content from Workshop.php.

So what's the best way to determine if a file doesn't exist and alternatively link to a different file?

There are two possible solutions that come to mind, though I don't really know how to implement either one...

1) The name of the static page I want to display (e.g. Ecology) will always match a value in a database table, field URL. So if my database table has the value "Migration," it will try to include a file named Migration.php. So maybe there's some sort of solution that would match a database value to a file's name.

2) If I include a file with the require command, and that file doesn't exist, it displays an error and kills my page. Is there a way to replace that error with a command to instead link to a different file?

Here's an example of one of my include scripts, where $MySite = the name of a website and $Section = the section (e.g. Topics).

```
require_once($BaseINC."/inc/D/$MySite/$Section/$URL.php");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$inc_file = $BaseINC."/inc/D/$MySite/$Section/$URL.php";
if (file_exists($inc_file)) {
    require_once($inc_file);
} else {
   // error message or default page or whatever
   exit();  // kills the rest of the code below
}
```

I assume your `$BaseINC` var has the rest of the absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that include pages is the better way to do it works.
You can save the data of the pages in the database too, and dynamic construct the pages.

Anyway, you can test if a file exists with the php function [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php) before require or include a file:

```
if(file_exists($filename){
     require_once($filename);
}
```